# Baseline profiles aren't supported on this device version

Tags: android, baseline-profile

I configured a benchmark module and created a baseline profile for the project and saved it in the app according to the instructions here https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/baselineprofiles.

I've also added the benchmark:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class BaselineProfileBenchmark {
    @get:Rule
    val benchmarkRule = MacrobenchmarkRule()

    @Test
    fun startupNoCompilation() {
        startup(CompilationMode.None())
    }

    @Test
    fun startupBaselineProfile() {
        startup(
            CompilationMode.Partial(
                baselineProfileMode = BaselineProfileMode.Require
            )
        )
    }

    private fun startup(compilationMode: CompilationMode) {
        benchmarkRule.measureRepeated(
            packageName = "com.example.app",
            metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
            iterations = 10,
            startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
            compilationMode = compilationMode
        ) {
            pressHome()
            startActivityAndWait()
        }
    }
}
```

`startupBaselineProfile()` test fails with an exception *"Baseline profiles aren't supported on this device version"*. I tried to run it on different Pixel and Samsung devices with the latest Android version, but the same exception is thrown everywhere.

Do these baseline profiles wok at all?

Comment: What Android version have you run them? There's currently a bug with Android 12L (API 32). Could you try different OS version? If it's not that, then could you try latest version of profile installer, which is 1.2.0-alpha02? Thanks!

Comment: @mlykotom Do you have a link to the Android 12L bug you mentioned? I get the same error on a Pixel 3 running Android 12.

Comment: Here's the bug you can track https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228222110

Comment: @mlykotom I was using version 1.0.4, switching to 1.2.0-alpha02 helps and it works on Android 12. Thanks!

Comment: posted it as an answer you can accept if it answered your question :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with Android 14 and implementation("androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.4.0-alpha01")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update October 2022

Use `androidx.profileinstaller` version `1.3.0-alpha01` or later that fixes the problem (or `1.2.1` when released).

### Original Answer

Currently baseline profiles has some known issues:

- can't benchmark them on Android 12L (Api 32) - [b/228222110](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228222110)
- you need latest alpha version of profileinstaller, which is 1.2.0-alpha02

Note, that the profileinstaller may be added with a library (e.g. jetpack compose) so make sure you add it to your dependencies to override the version.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to add the profileinstaller dependency to the target module (usually it's you app module)

```
implementation "androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.2.0-beta01"
```

Comment: Thank you for this, we should add it in app module